# How to do a LINQ-SQL query on a delimited column, without resorting to client-side evaluation

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-6

I am trying to query a view, which has an "Operator" column. Sample data:

- Ed
- Edward
- Ed;Adam
- [null]
- Bob; Edward
- Bob; Ed; Tom

Given a user input of a `List<string>`, let's say "Ed","Peter", "Mark", I want to return rows that fully contain one of the user inputs, in my example rows #1, #3, and #6.

An equivalent SQL query that returns what I want would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myview 
WHERE "Operator" LIKE 'Ed' OR "Operator" LIKE 'Ed;%' OR "Operator" LIKE '%;Ed' OR "Operator" LIKE '%;Ed;%' 
--repeated for "Peter" and "Mark" etc
```

I've tried #1:

```
var query = IQueryable<Myview> farms;
var List<string> operators = new List<string> { "Ed","Peter", "Mark" };

var filteredFarms = query.Where(t => t.Operator != null && operators.Any(op => t.Operator.Split(';').Any(o => o == op)));
```

Which unsurprisingly gives `"The LINQ expression ... could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'."`

I also tried #2:

```
var filteredFarms = query.Where(t => t.Operator != null && operators.Any(op => EF.Functions.Like(t.Operator, ""+op+";%")));
```

As a test to see if I could build the "like" query manually, but that failed with the same error.

Is there any way I can do this using LINQ without client-side evaluation? You may assume that ";" is only used as a separator.

Comment: Im probably wrong but in the SQL wouldnt you just be able to do LIKE "%Ed%" then I think that would do everything you're asking of it, then maybe in LINQ it should simply just be 

`var filteredFarms = query.Where(t => t.Operator != null && operators.Any(op => EF.Functions.Like(t.Operator, $"%{op}%")));`

Feels like this should work but im not 100%

Comment: @LiamKenny, no, the "%Ed% would also return "Edward" which is not a desired output. Further more, for some reason EF.Functions.Like keeps throwing that it cannot be translated, whether I use string concantenation or string interpolation.

Comment: There's no such thing as a delimited column. That's a single string. Treating it as multiple values is a fundamental table design bug. PostgreSQL has array types which *are* supported by NpgSQL and can be indexed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up moving part of the logic to an SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."FarmContainsOperator"(param_op TEXT, id bigint)
 RETURNS bigint
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    count integer; 
BEGIN
count :=  (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM public.myview WHERE 
        ("Operator" LIKE param_op OR 
        "Operator" LIKE param_op||';%' OR
        "Operator" LIKE '%;'||param_op OR
        "Operator" LIKE '%;'||param_op||';%') AND "farmID"=id
        );
return count;
END;
$function$
```

Then I declared that function in my model:

```
public static int FarmContainsOperator(string opName,long id) => throw new NotSupportedException();
```

And in the context:

```
modelBuilder
                .HasDbFunction(typeof(Myview).GetRuntimeMethod(nameof(Myview.FarmContainsOperator), new[] { typeof(string), typeof(long) }))
                .HasName("FarmContainsOperator");
```

So now I can do this:

```
var query = IQueryable<Myview> farms;
var List<string> operators = new List<string> { "Ed","Peter", "Mark" };

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Myview>(false);

foreach (string op in operators)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(x => Myview.FarmContainsOperator(op, x.farmID) > 0);
    
}
query = query.Where(predicate);
```

And it works. Probably it would be more efficient to use a TVF instead of scalar function, but it's sufficient for now.

Comment: That's a strong warning sign that you're doing something wrong. There's no such thing as a delimited column in relational databases. That's just a string. Trying to put multiple values in a single field violates the most basic table design rule. What you did has the worst possible performance too, because it can't use any indexes so it has to scan the entire table

Comment: PostgreSQL has [array types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) that can be [searched](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-SEARCHING), eg `WHERE 10000 = ANY (pay_by_quarter)` and [indexed with a GIN index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html#INDEXES-TYPES-GIN). In other databases you could use their JSON or XML support to store, query and sometimes index values instead of using string manipulations

Comment: NpgSQL [supports array types in EF Core](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/array.html). You can map an `Operators` array column to a `List<string> Operators` property and write `.Where(farm=>farm.Operators.Contains("jim")`

Comment: Thank you for the comments @PanagiotisKanavos and the frame-challenge. I'm well familiar with normalization. As I said in the original post, it's a view. It aggregates data which is stored in the appropriate normalized tables. The EF-model references that view, but has no direct knowledge of how the tables are joined. So, I could either spent countless hours to build an EF-model that references the same-tables that the view uses....or do what I did.

Comment: That's a sign of an inappropriate view. That will perform even worse. The alternative is to modify the view to return fields in a searchable form, map them to EF and use the correct operators. You can use `ARRAY_AGG` to aggregate to an array. You can use materialized views to index the array column. Or you can use a *different* view that *does* allow the queries you want.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as delimited columns in relational databases. These are just string values. They can't be queried or indexed. Trying to find a string in the middle of such a column will force the database to scan the entire table.

There's no need for such values in PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL has [array types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) that can be [searched](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-SEARCHING) using [array operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html):

```
CREATE TABLE Farms (
    ...
    Operators  text ARRAY,
    ...
);
CREATE INDEX idx_farm on "Farms" USING GIN ("Operators");
...

SELECT *
FROM Farms
WHERE Operators @> ARRAY['Joe']
```

NpgSQL supports [array mapping and querying](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/array.html). This means you can easily write a LINQ query that checks for an element in the array:

```
var query=dbContext.Farms.Where(farm=>farm.Operators.Contains("Joe"));
```

Array fields can be [indexed with a GIN index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html#INDEXES-TYPES-GIN), providing fast querying. Only [a few](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-builtin-opclasses.html#GIN-BUILTIN-OPCLASSES-TABLE) of the array operators take advantage of indexing though, which is why I used `@>` instead of `ANY`.

In other databases you could use their JSON or XML support to store, query and sometimes index values instead of using string manipulations

Comment: May I suggest adding here the ARRAY_AGG suggestion as well as the MATERIALIZED VIEW condition for completeness? It doesn't really answer the question asked, but if I had the time to do some major refactoring, I'd go with your route.

Comment: The question didn't say anything about views with aggregations. If it did, the answer would be different. There's `string_to_array` to split a delimited string into an array that can be searched. I don't know if that can be mapped to LINQ. The question has *two* problems - the view design and the mapping. The view problems make mapping harder

Comment: For example, you can probably map `List<string> Operators` to a formula using `string_to_array`. Whether you can use `Operator.Contains` after that though, depends on the provider. I haven't tested this

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
            List<string> query = new List<string>()
            {
                "Ed",
                "Edward",
                "Ed; Adam",
                null,
                "Bob; Edward",
                "Bob; Ed; Tom"
            };
            List<string> operators = new List<string> { "Ed", "Peter", "Mark" };

            var results = query.Where(x => x != null && x.Split(new char[] { ';' }).Any(y => operators.Any(z => y.Trim().Contains(z))));
```

Comment: It's almost identical to my #1 try, and it returns the same error:

[The query] could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'string.Split' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information.
Translation of method 'string.Split' failed. [ ...]